# IIS express doesn't serve portable network graphics

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

#### My Situation

I have built an website using ASP.NET MVC 5. The website is running on an IIS express (Windows 8). I have basic knowledge in webdevelopment, but I cannot figure out how to solve my problem.

#### The Problem

My IIS express doesn't serve my portable network graphics as expected. I am always seeing the default 404 page of the IIS express with the following default description:

```
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

#### First attempt

I tried to narrow down the problem by adding following code to my Global.asax.cs file. The request should only be processed, if the requested file is available. But the requested png is always available...

*Global.asax.cs (Snippet)*

```cs
public override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath))
    base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e); 
}
```

#### Second attempt

Because I thought it would be possible that my [IIS doesn't know][1] the MIME-Type of Portable Network Graphics, I ended up adding the static file handlers in my Web.Config:

*web.config (Snippet)*

```xml
  <add name="StaticFileTS"  verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.ts"  type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileMap" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.map" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileCss" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.css" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileJs"  verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.js"  type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFilePng" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.png" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileJpg" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileGif" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.gif" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add name="StaticFileIco" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.ico" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc" />
```

Can you please give me some idea, what I have forgotten? Do you need additional information?

Thanks :)

#### Update #1

The URL I want to call is: 
*http://localhost:60809/Merkliste/Images/Icons/ButtonBar/ButtonBarInclude/Download_All.png*

The physical file path is: 
*C:\softdev\Projectname\Areas\Merkliste\Images\Icons\ButtonBar\ButtonBarInclude\Download_All.png*

I already tried to set the build action of my image to *"embedded ressource"* instead of *"content"*.

Comment: What is the path to your file, what is the root of the web server, and what URL are you using to access it?

Comment: IIS express, by default, serves png files just fine. You shouldn't have to add mime types to the web.config at all. I'd look elsewhere for the problem if I were you.

Comment: Sounds like a routing problem to me...have you put in the appropriate ignore, or even you could use the StaticFileHandler instead of the MvcHttpHandler. The `MvcHttpHandler` suggests you would be streaming the file out from `.net`, whilst your language suggests you are trying to serve static files.

Comment: Feel free to write PNG instead of portable network graphics ;)

Comment: Have you checked your IIS logs to confirm that the 404 messages are related to the right files?  Also, have you checked via command-line to make sure the file extensions are intact?

Comment: Extensions are intact, the 404 message contained in the IIS log is also related to the right files.

Comment: Did you put the `PNG` file inside the `Content` folder? or did you put it somewhere else? If you put it somewhere else, you will get `404`

Comment: @th1rdey3 - This is wrong. I have lots of images in my %ROOT%/Areas/%Areaname%/Images/ directory. My scripts are placed in my %ROOT%/Areas/%Areaname%/Scripts/ directory. My stylesheets are placed in my %ROOT%/Areas/%Areaname%/Style/ directory. Everything is served just fine, except my stupid PNGs. Even my JPEGs are working :(

Comment: I created a `TempFolder` in the root of one of my mvc5 project and placed a png file there. Then when i tried to access it with `http://<host>:<port>/TempFolder/filename.png` i got 404. However when I place it inside `Contents` folder I was able to access it. I haven't check JPEGs

Comment: @th1rdey3 - This sounds interesting, but I couldn't find any reference which would prove your statement. I believe it's a matter of wrong routing, if you cannot access a file in a subfolder of your root directory, but mine is in a subfolder of my area directory.

Comment: I have read somewhere that MVC handles some folders differently. Like `Contents` folder. So any file inside `Contents` folder can be requested directly. I don't have the total list of which folders though. You could try creating a `Contents` folder inside your area folder and keeping the `png` file there. See if it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config try adding the mime type like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I would also investigate using fiddler to see the exact http request, it could be to do with your markup or css.

Comment: This looked so helpful :( But it wasn't. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: No worries. How are you accessing the image? What is the exact url that is failing?

Comment: You can find the exact url in the updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try including the file in your VS project.